# How do I programmatically automate .rmd file to PDF using knitr?

Tags: r, pdf-generation, reporting, knitr, rdoc

I can produce my reports rather quickly thanks to knitr and RDoc; however I want to streamline my process a little more by automatically generating the documents in my R script.

Do ya'lls have any solutions or resources I could use to further investigate to create a solution?

Comment: Munge don't mangle. Have you tried using knitr with PDF output mode?

Comment: Yes I can create it all in Rstudio; but I want to further automate this so that I can create a cron job.

Comment: You know you can knit things without using the "Knit" button by using command line and something like: Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('my_sweave_file.Rnw')"
pdflatex my_sweave_file.tex

Comment: Or even easier, if you're using Rmd files: knit2pdf(...)

Comment: Ok.. I'm just a little dense I guess; could not find exactly that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To automate a knitr job you can use something like the command line below.

```
Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit2pdf('myRnw.Rnw')"
```

Put that in a .sh file and you can cron tab it all you want.

Explanation (aka the same again in English):

- Rscript is the script-running version of R
- Rscript -e "myexpression();" is the expression runner, it runs everything in the quotes. See Rscript --help for more detail.
- library(knitr) -- well, you can't knit without knowing how, obviously neither can R
- knit2pdf( '/path/to/file', ...)  lookup the ? help on the function or search for more examples online.